# Process out of memory in php 7

Tags: php-7

I am trying to run a feed import process, but keep getting this. Should I increase some parameters in my php.ini? I tried but no luck..

```
 Out of memory: Kill process 1845 (php-fpm7.0) score 566 or sacrifice child
May 20 06:05:21  kernel: [1278231.829579] Killed process 1845 (php-fpm7.0) total-vm:521780kB, anon-rss:258000kB, file-rss:28036kB
```

thanks

Comment: Is this something you are encountering only with PHP 7 (and not older versions)? This looks like a genuine out of memory condition (not just a memory limit), so changing the php.ini will not help.